# Adicionar constante a cada chave de um array

Tags: php, array

Como incluir uma constante em determinada chave de cada array. Exemplo:

Array sem alteração:

```
   array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'image' => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bmw' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'image' => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'mercedes' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'image' => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bentley' (length=9)
```

Array com alteração:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://exemplo.com/1.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bmw' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://exemplo.com/2.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'mercedes' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'image' => string 'http://exemplo.com/3.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bentley' (length=9)
```

Comment: Qual é a constante e em qual chave?

Comment: O que pretende é construir o *url* da imagem prefixando `http://www.exemplo.com/` em todos os campos `image` ?

Comment: Em qual momento essa constante entra em ação? ou tem que varrer esse array e atribuir? a sua pergunta está incompleta poderia explicar esses pontos.